# Solving a $3\times3$ system of linear equations.

Tags: systems-of-equations, substitution

I have the following as a given:

$2x + y = 22$

$2z + x = 28$

$2y + z = 38$

Solve for $x, y$ and $z$

P.S. I tried solving it by substitution and elimination but neither is working.

Thanks[image][image][image]

Comment: Post those "substation and eliminitaion" efforts.

Comment: @Ripi2 done, I posted the pictures

Comment: You seem to have started out by adding the first two equations.  Try eliminating $x$ from the first two equations instead.  Then you'll have two equations in $y$ and $z$.

Comment: $2$ times the second equation minus the first equation gives you an equation without $x$. Now, you have two equations without $x$. Solve for $y$ and $z$. Then, backsolve for $x$.

Comment: I tried this, ended up with z equals 14.4 which didn’t work, I know that I am doing something wrong but I don’t  know what

Comment: I think you're going too fast, doing most of work "at head". Start writting the first equation and below it 2 times the second. Then write their substration. Go on, slowly and writting it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$9y= (2x+y)-2(2z+x) +4(2y+z) $$ $$=22-2\cdot 28+4\cdot 38$$ $$\implies y=...$$

Comment: I did this and ended with y = 13.112, let me check if this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

if we add up all the equations, we get
$x+y+z=\frac{88}{3}$ $$y=\frac{88}{3}-x-y $$  use first equation
$x=22-\frac{88}{3}-z $ let's Express x through the previous equality 
$y=\frac{88}{3}-22+\frac{88}{3}+z-z$ 
$\Rightarrow $
$y=\frac{110}{3}$ 
use first equation of system 
$$2x=22-y=\frac{-22}{3} $$
And finally find $z $ 
$$2z=28+\frac{22}{3} $$ and $z=\frac{53}{3} $
Solution $(\frac{-22}{3},\frac{110}{3},\frac{53}{3}) $